# System.Security.Cryptography.Xml in portable class library?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, signedxml

I'm using a licensing tool (Rhino.Licensing) that uses signed XML files as licenses.

Since the `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` namespace is not available on varios platforms (like MonoTouch and Mono for Android, etc) its not possible to validate a license and its signature.

Is there a way to read and validate signed XML files on the portable class library platform?

I currently need this feature on .NET, Mono, MonoTouch, Mono for Android, WinRT, Silverlight, MonoGame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK (there's too many profile in PCL 2.0) `System.Security.dll` is not part of any portable library profile.

- .NET: part of the framework
- Mono: part of the framework
- MonoTouch : **not part of the profile**
- Mono for Android : **not part of the profile**
- WinRT : *not sure*
- Silverlight : **not part of the profile**
- MonoGame : not a profile - it will depend on which profile it is used

The **good news** is that you could build your own using Mono's source code. That should be pretty easy for MonoTouch and Mono for Android.

The only problem I can foresee is Silverlight since it did not (last time I checked) support RSA and Mono's BigInteger implementation requires **unsafe** code (which was also not allowed under most circumstances). OTOH, and with a bit more work, you could re-implement RSA using SL's `System.Numerics.dll`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But i simply ported BouncyCastle to the PCL profile and wrote my own [Portable.Licensing](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing) framework.